# Google API authorisation with GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker: how to manage multiple users in web application?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am calling Google Api authentication using this function

```
public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService GetService()
        {
            //get Credentials from client_secret.json file 
            UserCredential credential;
            var CSPath = MyServer.MapPath("Content");

            using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(CSPath, "client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))            {
                
                string credPath = MyServer.MapPath("content/token");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }

            //create Drive API service.
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "GoogleDriveRestAPI-v3",
            });
            return service;
        }
```

It is storing Token in content\token folder under the application.

I am using this function to retrive some files from user Google Drive.

It is working fine for one user, but I want to implement it in a we app so that each user will
retrieve the file from his own Google Drive account.

This senario is working well with [Google File Picker](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview)

My question is to allow each user to use hios own google drive account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync uses fileDatastore by default it stores the user credentials in the machines %appdata% folder.  The name of the file it creates for the users credentials is denoted by "user".

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretsJsonFilePath
                                   ,FileMode.Open
                                   ,FileAccess.Read))
      {   
      credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
      GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
      new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,  DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
      "LookIAmAUniqueUser",
       CancellationToken.None,
      new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")                               
      ).Result;
      }
```

would result in

> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-LookIAmAUniqueUser.TokenResponse-LookIAmAUniqueUser

[Google .net – FileDatastore demystified](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

So if you change  "user" you will be storing it as a different user.  As you are running this as an installed application you will need to implement some way for your  desktop app to know its a different user. Then just send a different string for each user.